# State 'boto_rds.present' is unavailable. Ec2/saltstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-rds, salt-stack

Im trying to create a RDS instance using boto_rds.present, the code looks like:

```
rds_instance_abc:
  boto_rds.present:
    - name: learn_rds1
    - allocated_storage: 10
    - storage_type: gp2
    - db_name: abc_testing
    - db_instance_class: db.t2.micro
    - engine: MySQL
    - master_username: root
    - master_user_password: root
    - region: us-east-1}
    - keyid: fsdfsdfsdfs
    - key: fsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsfsdfs
```

After `salt-call state.highstate` I have this **error:**

```
local:
----------
          ID: rds_instance_abc
    Function: boto_rds.present
        Name: learn_rds1
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'boto_rds.present' found in SLS u'tester' is unavailable
     Started:
    Duration:
     Changes:

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1

I have installed boto in my instance: pip27 install boto
```

If I use the [boto’s RDS interface](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rds_tut.html) via shell, the rds instance is created fine.

Do I missing something in my state?

This is the version report:

```
Salt: 2014.7.5
         Python: 2.6.9 (unknown, Apr  1 2015, 18:16:00)
         Jinja2: 2.7.2
       M2Crypto: 0.21.1
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
        libnacl: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.10
          ioflo: Not Installed
          PyZMQ: 14.3.1
           RAET: Not Installed
            ZMQ: 3.2.5
           Mako: Not Installed
```

Comment: What version of Salt are you running?

Comment: @mafro: I updated the post with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto_rds Salt module isn't available in the 2014.7 branch. it made it into the 2015.5 branch, which should be released soon.

You could probably take the boto_rds.py module and state and deploy them from your /srv/salt/_modules and /srv/salt/_state directories on your Salt master.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/58c7ba2b5fc68f5d1fad6540900560b990bc90f7/salt/states/boto_rds.py#L6